# get battery level from electric car via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible when when you connect to Bluetooth with a car that you can fetch it's battery level? What would you need to use in Android Studio to achieve this?

Comment: android studio is an IDE, using it is entirely optional, so your question is actually just regarding android itself. `Is it possible when when you connect to Bluetooth with a car that you can fetch it's battery level?` i think this is going to heavily rely on available technology, a bit too broad for us to help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with ODB2, [AndrODB](https://github.com/fr3ts0n/AndrOBD/) is an open source Android project that might already do what you want.

If this information (battery level) is not available in the ODB protocol you have to go a level lower and look into CAN bus.

Comment: So this has to have an adaptor?

Comment: Yes, ELM327 compatible adapter. You can't do it without an adapter, the information you see on your car entertainment system is not accessible through an API or something. Some car brands come with an app that can display car information on your phone.

Comment: Okay so getting this kind of information can't be done with generic methods. Thanks for the information.